# Azure Data Factory v1 pipeline not starting

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created an Azure Data Factory which has the following activity JSON as viewed in the portal (excerpt)

```
   "start": "2018-07-27T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2099-12-30T13:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "runtimeInfo": {
        "deploymentTime": "2020-06-08T12:42:21.2801494Z",
        "activePeriodSetTime": "2020-06-08T12:23:16.2436361Z",
        "pipelineState": "Running",
        "activityPeriods": {
            "copyXZActivity": {
                "start": "2017-06-27T00:00:00Z",
                "end": "2099-12-30T13:00:00Z"
            }
        }
    },
    "id": "ef896997-2046-4b2e-7074-ecb5f58dd489",
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "hubName": "sxdb_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
```

My AzureSQLTable inputs and outputs have the following JSON config:

```
"availability": {
      "frequency": "Minute",
      "interval": 15
    },
```

I would expect it to run immediately, every 15 minutes, but the activity window is empty. The next scheduled run at 5/3/2020, 4:30 PM UTC according to the activity window, which seems to be a random date in the past.

How do I get the activity to run, as expected, every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been this line, which caused execution to begin on 3 May 2020:

```
"copyXZActivity": {
                "start": "2017-06-27T00:00:00Z",
```

Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
 "copyXZActivity": {
                    "start": "2020-06-10T00:00:00Z",
```

Changing the start date to the current date got the activity running. It appears like Data Factory 1, when given a start date in the distant past, chooses another date a few months ago, and starts executing the activity from that day, continuously, until it "catches up" and then follows the interval pattern (although I wasn't able to navigate via the monitoring UI to that date).

It exhibits this "catch up" behavior with any start date/time in the past.